# Java Jackson deserialization efficiency: is it safe to an HTTP response as byte-array?

Tags: java, json, jackson

From [Jackson's best practices section](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation:-Jackson-Performance):

> Input: byte[] is best if you have it; InputStream second best; followed by Reader -- and in every case, do NOT try reading input into a String!

> Output: OutputStream is best; Writer second best; and calling writeValueAsString() is the least efficient (why construct an intermediate String?)

I currently work on an app (Dropwizard) that reads a relatively big HTTP response every minute, in this fashion:

```
HttpRequest request = httpBuilder.build();
HttpResponse<String> responseresponse = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
MyDeserializedClass deserResponse = objMapper.readValue(response.body(), MyDeserializedClass.class);
```

If I understand things correctly, it'd be much more beneficial to read the HTTP response and have Jackson deserialize the `byte[]` instead of `String`, like so:

```
HttpRequest request = httpBuilder.build();
// Notice: BodyHandlers.ofByteArray()
HttpResponse<byte[]> responseresponse = httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofByteArray());
MyDeserializedClass deserResponse = objMapper.readValue(response.body(), MyDeserializedClass.class);
```

- This should be more efficient memory-wise, correct?

However, I've read about some limitations regarding byte-arrays and non-ASCII characters, and with my lack of knowledge I'm concerned that reading the response as `byte[]` instead of `String` will result in accented characters getting malformed? On the other hand, nowhere do I see the encoding of the response being specified when reading as `String`, so I guess it's safe to read the response in this manner? (and, the response is originally a `bytearray[]` when coming in if I understand correctly)

Comment: Yes, reading as a byte[] is fine. Directly reading from the request's `InputStream` would be even better. I'm not sure why Jackson claims differently: The same logic as for the output applies: Why construct an intermediate?

Comment: As for using the correct String encoding, you'll need to account for that anyway. Having Jackson convert the bytes to String or doing it yourself doesn't matter. As long as you're using the correct encoding (probably UTF-8), you'll be fine.

Comment: @Jorn Thank you. Can you please add this as an answer and clarify the following: "Yes, reading as a byte[] is fine." - is it better than reading from `String` though?